# Как из .py сделать .exe и .app в Python 3.10?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.10

Пытался из .py файла сделать .exe и .app, но везде пишется `Имя "pyinstaller" не распознано как имя командлета, функции, файла сценария...`. Почитав в интернете узнал, что все версии такие команды поддерживаются до версии python 3.7. Как тогда в более новых версия создавать файл другого формата?

Comment: Этот пакет необходимо установить pip install pyinstaller. И лучше это делать в виртуальном окружении

Comment: @Виктор данный инструмент не доступен в 3.10 (судя по документации и словам людей из интернета)

Comment: Странно это, а у меня всё работает :) Python 3.11.0. Доверяй, но ПРОВЕРЯЙ

Comment: Принимайте мой ответ как верный, и закрывайте вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну в итоге:

1. cmd.exe
2. python -m venv C:\Projects\taskPyinst
3. cd C:\Projects\taskPyinst
4. Scripts\activate.bat
5. pip install wheell
6. pip install pyinstaller

test.py:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Hello pyinstaller!!")
    input()
```

7. pyinstaller -w -F --console test.py
8. cd dist
9. test.exe

Вывод:

```
C:\Projects\taskPyinst\dist>test.exe
Hello pyinstaller!!
```

PS:
Желательно скачать upx.exe и положить его туда, где путь прописан в PATH. Тогда pyinstaller ещё пожмёт EXE файл

Результаты с UPX и без:

```
12.11.2022  14:00         7 767 866 test.exe
12.11.2022  13:59         6 719 992 test_UPX.exe
```

Comment: а что там жать упх?  там же простой самораспаковывающийся архив с кодом на выходе

Comment: Файлы, которые внутри. Там находятся DLL файлы

Comment: Благодарю, а то весь интернет излазил, не находил. Вопрос только на счёт библиотек и app. Они устанавливаются после 4 пункта? И формата app случаем не знаете как сделать?

Comment: @OtetsValerian Ставить можно после 4-пункта , но перед запуском pyinstaller :)

Comment: @OtetsValerian не понял про "И формата app случаем не знаете как сделать" - какого формата?

Comment: @Виктор это формат файла для Mac os, для виндовс exe. Если exe на маке можно запускать, то тогда не надо. Просто читал, что там другой формат

Comment: @OtetsValerian https://pyinstaller.org/en/v4.2/usage.html - там про Mac есть, надо собирать только под Mac OS как я понял (могу ошибаться). Опция там --osx-bundle-identifier

Comment: @OtetsValerian Пишут, что под Mac OS запускать нужно, и без параметра --osx-bundle-identifier (подпись) тоже работает https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64954725/how-to-use-pyinstaller-for-macos-big-sur

Comment: @Виктор То есть только на системе Mac OS надо собирать или просто указать параметр?

Comment: На Mac OS собирать